# Qt5 storing list of websocket clients

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, websocket, qt5

I am trying to store a list of connected QWebSockets in a QHash for a subscription purpose.

A client connects and then sends the websocket server a feature they would like to subscribe to. Each feature set has a QHash that they get added to. When the feature has new information, it loops through the clients in the QHash and sends them a message.

That seems to work fine, but if a client disconnects and then the feature tries to send them a message my application seg faults. On a client disconnect I am trying to remove the client from the QHash but the Qhash::remove function always returns 0.

The way I'm storing Websocket clients is with a pointer to the QWebSocket object as a hash:

```
QHash<QWebSocket *, QString> diagnosticSubscriptions;
```

When a client subscribes to the diagnostics feature in my textMessageReceived function I run:

```
QWebSocket *pClient = qobject_cast<QWebSocket *>(sender());
diagnosticSubscriptions.insert(pClient, callback);
```

Then when the user disconnects I try to clean up the QHash:

```
QWebSocket *pClient = qobject_cast<QWebSocket *>(sender());
diagnosticSubscriptions.remove(pClient);
pClient->deleteLater();
```

If I print the result of remove it is 0 so the client isn't being removed.

Is there a better way of storing QWebSockets?

Comment: I reconnect same QWebSocket object in the code for a long time and it works. Of course you can follow an example where they dispose of it. Something strange is going on and the context is not enough to judge. Consider using QPointer to detect whether the object was already deleted.